# Echo php code in javascript file

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script.js file, i need to echo some piece of **PHP** code in it like,

```
if($.fn.checkbox) {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').checkbox({
        cls : 'checkbox',
        empty : '<?=base_url()?>public/img/sprites/forms/checkboxes/empty.png'//it is just example "<?=base_url()?>"to clarify, i know we cant actually echo here..
    }); 
}
```

is it possible, i didn't find any good solution,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write your code like this in php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var base_url    =   '<?php echo base_url()?>'
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='script.js'></script>
```

`base_url` will now be available in script.js

Comment: this is the only short and useful solution

Answer (score 2):

On page load assign that to a variable.

```
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
```

Then use it later.

```
empty: base_url+'public/img/sprites/forms/checkboxes/empty.png'
```

Comment: i recommend create a function.js file and load it before your script.js. define the base_url there so base_url will be available everywhere

Comment: it is the same solution that i questioned except assigning it to a variable, although, it is not working in .js file..

Comment: @faanahmed how do you expect Apache to parse `php code` that resides in `js file` without the use of `an AddHandler`? Also, thanks for the downvote from whomever.

Comment: you need to write code in two different files. In one file it will not work.

Comment: @Naeem Just like this in .htaccess `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .js`

Comment: i haven't privileges to down, i was expecting a type of @raheel shan's solution, but still i need to define base_url twice in script as well as in php file..

Comment: @Ohgodwhy when i add your handler line, and refresh my browser it run and ask me to download file as application/x-httpd-php (5.9 KB) ? am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than saving file as script.js save file as script.php and write your script in `<script>` tag.

and write your PHP code something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 var test = <?php echo "test"; ?>

 //your code

});

</script>
```